# PHP ternary operators

Tags: php, ternary

I have written a ternary function in PHP and it seems to work, although I am not sure if it is correct, can someone take a look and tell me if it is right?

I have added the ternary and the if of what should be happening.

```
    //Foreach Loop
    foreach ($post as $item) {
        //If of what should occur
        if ($passed == true) {
            if (is_numeric($item)) {
                if ($item > 0) {
                    $passed = true;
                }
                else {
                    $passed = false;
                }
            }
            else {
                if ($item != "") {
                    $passed = true;
                }
                else {
                    $passed = false;
                }
            }
            //Ternary operator.
            $passed = (is_numeric($item) ? ($item > 0 ? true : false) : ($item != "" ? true : false));
        }
        else {
            return $passed;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can down vote tell me on what grounds they did it? (Want to know how to improve!) :)

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted but the reason might be _can someone take a look and tell me if it is right_

Comment: The `$passed` is declared before the `foreach` loop

Comment: @PEM do you have any documented evidence proving  ternaries are slower? or is this personal opinion. To the OP there is a code review stack overflow for this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Dave While this may be a little old : http://fabien.potencier.org/the-php-ternary-operator-fast-or-not.html 
I also noted that on several tests on my own use-cases. But again, it's more readability if you ask me :)

Comment: Nested ternary operators are bad if you ask me : you save a few lines/characters of code while losing much in readibility. each time you or a colleague will have to look at this part of code, he will have to draw himself a mental image of the "if" you just posted, and that's losing time !

Comment: @PEM interesting read I've never seen that before ta for link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please have a look on corrected code

```html
$passed = (is_numeric($item))?($item>0?true:false):($item !="" ? true:false);
```

Answer (score -1):

Honestly I do not really understand why you do not use a

```
if (!empty($item)) { 
    $passed = true; 
} else {
    return false; 
}
```

In any case, ternaries are less readable than if /elseif / else, they are also slower (note that it is not an universal truth but a more general use case thing http://fabien.potencier.org/the-php-ternary-operator-fast-or-not.html). 
I would recommend, if you really need all these if and elses to keep them rather than using ternaries (for readability's purpose).

Comment: Some people have a habit of downvoting without saying why they did it... It's about time SO asks downvoters to explain why they do so.